# Ideas for a hero using lightning to incapacitate captors - on a ship in the middle of an electrical storm

Tags: magic, physics, electricity, lightning

I think it's mostly in the title - but I have my team of 'good guys' who come across an enemy ship in a mother of an electrical storm. They will get captured by the bad guys, but I would like the hero to somehow harness / conduct the electricity of a lightning strike to knock out the bad guys and give the good guys the advantage. My hero may already have some kind of tool for this purpose, or it could be something she sees and grabs. I like the idea of the captors using some kind of chain, which is used against them. I would like it even better if through some clever technique the lightning can pass through /  bypass the good guys even though they're in the way. The story is fantasy, so while I'd like the answer to be plausible, I think some minor bending of physics will be okay. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You included magic in your question, so inwould reccomend elaborating a little more on what exactly your magic system entails, and what makes an acceptable answer, otherwise is will be closed as too broad/unclear what you're asking/primarily opinion based. Not sure which one, though.

Comment: Short of an electrical storm that can vapourize your ship (I assume that your "good guys" would prefer not to do that), I think you are barking up the wrong tree (almost literally). You see, ships out at sea often encounter electrical storms. These same ships are often hit by these electrical storms (there aren't many tall buildings in the middle of the ocean). Therefore ships will often build a lightning rod INTO the ship based around the tallest part (the mast, which is a tree trunk).

Comment: Okay, thanks - I think I'm going to have to think about what I'm really asking and how / whether magic should be involved...